# Error in Custom Domain Name for my Tumblr account

Tags: redirects, dns, tumblr

I have a top level domain (harib.co.in) which already hosts a WordPress powered blog. I need to associate it with my tumblr account (harihb.tumblr.com). In my blog settings screen, I selected 'Use custom domain name' and entered my domain name there. When I clicked the button "Test your domain", it says

```
This subdomain’s CNAME is not pointing to Tumblr. You need to change your subdomain’s CNAME to:
    domains.tumblr.com
```

I logged in to my registrar's control panel and deleted the existing A records and added a CNAME record. It finally looks like this

```
harib.co.in    domains.tumblr.com
```

After waiting for about a day, I still couldn't get the redirection done.

[image]

Please let me know what is the mistake that I'm doing?

EDIT: Now, I am getting page not found error whenever I try to access harib.co.in which means the CNAME has been validated, right? However, the settings in Tumblr page still gives

```
This subdomain’s CNAME is not pointing to Tumblr. You need to change your subdomain’s CNAME to:
    domains.tumblr.com
```

Comment: It seems to be working just fine now. Have you [flushed your browser's DNS cache](http://dyn.com/web-browser-dns-caching-bad-thing/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because DNS records are systematically cached, it generally takes up to 48 hours for changes to propagate throughout the rest of the system. Flushing your browser's DNS cache may not necessarily resolve the issue right away, due to the various different levels at which this caching happens (your records may be up to date with respect to your ISP, but your ISP may not have received the changes just yet themselves).

It looks as though everything is in order now, however, and the behavior you describe is normal for that span of time. Generally, unless it is taking significantly more than 72 hours for your changes to take effect (which you can test with tools like [What's My DNS](http://www.whatsmydns.net/)), there is no cause for alarm.